# Adding a post on a form in PHP

Tags: php

When i click on the add menu link in order to fill a post from a form , the add button do not work. But when i refresh the page without clicking on the add menu link the add button works well.

here is the menu links :

```
<ul class="sidebar-nav">                    
<li>
    <a class="collapsed" href="#sidebar-ui" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#sidebar">
        <span class="icon">
           <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-right"></i>
        </span>
        MENU

    </a>
    <ul id="sidebar-ui" class="collapse">
        <li><a href="form_ajout.php" target="content-wrap" hover="red">Ajouter</a></li>
        <li><a href="Lister.php" target="content-wrap">Afficher</a></li>
        <li><a href="modifier_BD.php" target="content-wrap">Modifier</a></li>
        <li><a href="supprimer.php" target="content-wrap">Supprimer</a></li>
        <li><a href="consulter.php" target="content-wrap">Consulter</a></li>
        <li><a href="rechercher.php" target="content-wrap">Rechercher</a></li>
        <li><a href="galerie.php" target="content-wrap">Galeries</a></li>
        <li><a href="afficher.php" target="content-wrap">Excel file</a></li>

    </ul>
</li>
```

and here is the form :

```
<form id="validation-form" class="form-horizontal form-label-left" method="post" data-parsley-priority-enabled="false" novalidate="" action="ajout_BD.php">
<fieldset>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="basic">NOM :</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="text" id="basic" name="Nom" class="form-control " data-parsley-trigger="change" required="required" data-parsley-id="1769" placeholder="Entrez votre Nom ">
                <ul class="parsley-errors-list" id="parsley-id-1769">
                <li class="parsley-required">Champ obligatoire.</li>                                            </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="basic-change">
                Pr&eacute;nom :

            </label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="text" id="basic-change" name="Prenom" class="form-control " data-parsley-trigger="change" required="required" data-parsley-id="9306" placeholder="Entrez votre Pr&eacute;nom ">
                <ul class="parsley-errors-list filled" id="parsley-id-9306">

                <li class="parsley-required">Champ obligatoire.</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="email">
                E-mail
            </label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="email" id="email" name="Email" class="form-control " data-parsley-trigger="change" data-parsley-validation-threshold="1" required="required" data-parsley-id="2751" placeholder="Entrer votre E-mail">
                <ul class="parsley-errors-list filled" id="parsley-id-7040">
                <li class="parsley-required">Champ obligatoire.</li>
                <li class="parsley-type">Cette valeur doit correspondre &agrave; un E-mail valide.</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="number">
                T&eacute;l&eacute;phone :
            </label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="text" id="number" name="Telephone" class="form-control" data-parsley-type="number" required="required" data-parsley-id="2157" placeholder="Entrez votre T&eacute;l&eacute;phone"><ul class="parsley-errors-list" id="parsley-id-2157"></ul>
                <ul class="parsley-errors-list filled" id="parsley-id-1434">
                <li class="parsley-required">Champ obligatoire.</li>
                </ul>                               
            </div>
        </div>

        </div>
</fieldset>

<div class="form-actions">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-rounded pull-right" name="valider" value="Ajouter"/>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-rounded" name="Annuler" ><a href="NewMenu.php">Annuler</a></button>
</div>
```

PS: The validation form and the menu are in the same page. It is in French so the add button value is *Ajouter*. The same value for the   add link menu.

Comment: The file where both of these pieces of code are in is called: form_ajout.php?

Comment: Yes the adding form page in where there is the form is named : form_ajout.php , and the ajout_BD.php is the page that submits the filled information from the add button.

Answer (score 0):

here is the page code that fills the information posted from the form_ajout.php page into the database  , this code is separated on an other page which is : ajout_BD.php   .

```
<?php
//connexion à SQL et sélection de la base
include("connexion.php");


$_Nom=$_POST['Nom'];
$_Prenom = $_POST['Prenom'];
$_Email = $_POST['Email'];
$_Tel = $_POST['Telephone'];
$Date = date("Y-m-d");

if(($_Nom == "")||($_Email==""))
{
echo "vous devez remplir les champs nom et email ! <br>";
}
else
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO etudiants (Nom, Prenom, Email, Telephone, Date) VALUES ('$_Nom','$_Prenom','$_Email','$_Tel','$Date')" ;
    mysqli_query($db,$sql);
    mysqli_close($db);
```

if($sql){

```
echo "<h2>Etudiant ajout&eacute; avec succ&egrave;s !</h2>";
}
```

}
?>